# How do I make the text inside a text box to appear like textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a text box that I can manually paste text into and then click the copy button to select all the text in the box to my clipboard. But the text is in one long line, but I want it to look more like a paragraph. This is my code so far.

HTML

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="textBox" style="height:500px; width:1000px;">

<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy Text
  </button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("textBox");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");

  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use textarea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `textarea` with `col` and `rows` to increase size.

You can get more info about `textarea` on [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

Run snippet below to see it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("textBox");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textBox"rows="10" cols="50">Hello World</textarea>

<div class="tooltip">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy Text
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead.

```
<textarea id="textBox" rows="100" cols="100">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) element for this.

also, your javascript does not need this line:
`copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using "contenteditable" property. You can add this to any html element.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="textBox" style="height:500px; width:1000px;" />

<div class="tooltip">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
    Copy Text
  </button>
</div>
```

And then in our myFunction:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  const el = document.getElementById("textBox");
  const content = el.innerHtml;
  // ... do your stuff with content;
};
```

Contenteditable can be applied to every valid html tag in order to make its content editable. Technically you can apply it to everything on your page to make everything editable in your browser :)